# EF: Is it OK to use default value for the created date property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to set the `CreatedDate` column to the current datetime whenever a new row is inserted, so I made it like this:

```
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

I tested it and it works just fine, Is this a practical approach? I saw many articles achieve the same with so much code and using fluent API, no one mentioned this simple method?

Comment: One issue you may have is that this time would be generated based on the location of where the application server is running. If you have user interaction and would like to reflect the timezone the user is in this will not work. Without knowing your application however this may not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you want to accomplish.

> I saw many articles achieve the same with so much code and using fluent API,

Most of those articles will be about adding default values at the database level. You're not doing that. If you insert a row into your table using plain SQL, and don't specify a value for `CreatedDate`, you'll get an error.

With what you're doing, `CreatedDate` always needs to be specified in SQL when inserting. But Entity Framework *will* always specify it in the SQL when inserting, and completely ignore any default value set at the database level.

So if that's what you want -- the default value only gets applied when creating objects through C# -- then what you're doing is totally fine. It may also be written as setting the value from inside the class's constructor.

@Alex Kozlowski raises a good comment though, which is that `DateTime.Now` may not be the value you expect to be inserted. It depends on which system is running the code. The time zone may be different from your server's, or the clock may be out of sync.

Comment: And how can I avoid this "server time conflict" problem?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed You could avoid the different time zones by storing all times in UTC, but the clock being off is something that cannot reliably be prevented other than by letting one dedicated server (typically the database server) retrieve the time. And to make that play nice with EF, you get exactly to the database-level defaults that you're now managing to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This feature was added in c# version 6 onwards. This will work from c#-6 onwards only. And that's why you won't find it in many articles.